# Inline NOPs not optimized out in LLVM

Tags: gcc, assembly, arm, llvm

I'm working through an example in [this overview](http://www.ethernut.de/en/documents/arm-inline-asm.html) of compiling inline ARM assembly using GCC. Rather than GCC, I'm using llvm-gcc 4.2.1, and I'm compiling the following C code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void) {
    printf("Volatile NOP\n");
    asm volatile("mov r0, r0");
    printf("Non-volatile NOP\n");
    asm("mov r0, r0");
    return 0;
}
```

Using the following commands:

```
llvm-gcc -emit-llvm -c -o compiled.bc input.c
llc -O3 -march=arm -o output.s compiled.bc
```

My output.s ARM ASM file looks like this:

```
    .syntax unified
    .eabi_attribute 20, 1
    .eabi_attribute 21, 1
    .eabi_attribute 23, 3
    .eabi_attribute 24, 1
    .eabi_attribute 25, 1
    .file   "compiled.bc"
    .text
    .globl  main
    .align  2
    .type   main,%function
main:                                   @ @main
@ BB#0:                                 @ %entry
    str lr, [sp, #-4]!
    sub sp, sp, #16
    str r0, [sp, #12]
    ldr r0, .LCPI0_0
    str r1, [sp, #8]
    bl  puts
    @APP
    mov r0, r0
    @NO_APP
    ldr r0, .LCPI0_1
    bl  puts
    @APP
    mov r0, r0
    @NO_APP
    mov r0, #0
    str r0, [sp, #4]
    str r0, [sp]
    ldr r0, [sp, #4]
    add sp, sp, #16
    ldr lr, [sp], #4
    bx  lr
@ BB#1:
    .align  2
.LCPI0_0:
    .long   .L.str

    .align  2
.LCPI0_1:
    .long   .L.str1

.Ltmp0:
    .size   main, .Ltmp0-main

    .type   .L.str,%object          @ @.str
    .section    .rodata.str1.1,"aMS",%progbits,1
.L.str:
    .asciz   "Volatile NOP"
    .size   .L.str, 13

    .type   .L.str1,%object         @ @.str1
    .section    .rodata.str1.16,"aMS",%progbits,1
    .align  4
.L.str1:
    .asciz   "Non-volatile NOP"
    .size   .L.str1, 17
```

The two NOPs are between their respective @APP/@NO_APP pairs. My expectation is that the `asm()` statement without the volatile keyword will be optimized out of existence due to the -O3 flag, but clearly both inline assembly statements survive.

Why does the `asm("mov r0, r0")` line not get recognized and removed as a NOP?

Comment: When you write inline assembly, you get what you write. The compiler makes no attempt to optimize the inline assembly that you write.

Comment: @Mystical According to the linked article: "When adding assembly language code by using inline assembler statements, this code is also processed by the C compiler's code optimizer." Is the author incorrect, and if so, can you link me to documentation about how LLVM handles this?

Comment: That just means that it can optimize the entire inline assembly statement. But it will not go inside it and try to mess with the instructions themselves. The optimizer will treat the entire inline assembly statement as a black-box. It can remove or duplicate it if no side-effects are specified. But since you specified `volatile`, it will assume that it has side-effects and will not even touch it.

Comment: If this is good enough, I can make it an answer. But my only experience with inline assembly is in GCC and ICC. So I'm not sure if it's any different with the LLVM optimizers.

Comment: @Mystical The point of my example was to see the difference in the way that the compiler handles `asm()` NOPs based on whether they are marked `volatile`, which is why I have one of each. The linked article specifically says that if this NOP isn't marked `volatile`, then "if you never use any of the output operands in the remaining part of the C program, the optimizer will most likely remove your inline assembler statement".

Comment: volatile is not about not removing or removing asm statement. Volatile with asm block instructs compiler to not reorder asm statement with its neighbor statements.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As [Mystical](https://stackoverflow.com/users/922184/mysticial) and [Mārtiņš Možeiko](https://stackoverflow.com/users/675078/mrtis-mozeiko) have describe the compiler does not *optimize* the code; ie, change the instructions.  What the compiler does *optimize* is when the instruction is scheduled.  When you use `volatile`, then the compiler will not *re-schedule*.  In your example, *re-scheduling* would be moving before or after the `printf`.

The other *optimization* the compiler might make is to get **C** values to register for you.  Register allocation is very important to *optimization*.  This doesn't optimize the **assembler**, but allow the compiler to do *sensible* things with other code with-in the function.

To see the effect of `volatile`, here is some sample code,

```
int example(int test, int add)
{
  int v1=5, v2=0;
  int i=0;
  if(test) {
    asm volatile("add %0, %1, #7" : "=r" (v2) : "r" (v2));
    i+= add * v1;
    i+= v2;
  } else {
    asm ("add %0, %1, #7" : "=r" (v2) : "r" (v2));
    i+= add * v1;
    i+= v2;
  }
  return i;
}
```

The two branches have identical code except for the `volatile`.  `gcc` 4.7.2 generates the following code for an ARM926,

```
example:
   cmp  r0, #0
   bne  1f           /* branch if test set? */
   add  r1, r1, r1, lsl #2
   add  r0, r0, #7   /* add seven delayed */
   add  r0, r0, r1
   bx   lr
1: mov  r0, #0       /* test set */
   add  r0, r0, #7   /* add seven immediate */
   add  r1, r1, r1, lsl #2
   add  r0, r0, r1
   bx   lr
```

**Note:** The assembler branches are reversed to the 'C' code.  The 2nd branch is slower on some processors due to pipe lining.  The compiler prefers that

```
   add  r1, r1, r1, lsl #2
   add  r0, r0, r1
```

do not execute sequentially.

The [Ethernut ARM Tutorial](http://www.ethernut.de/en/documents/arm-inline-asm.html) is an excellent resource.  However, *optimize* is a bit of an overloaded word.  The compiler doesn't analyze the assembler, only the arguments and where the code will be **emitted**.

Answer (score 1):

`volatile` is implied if the `asm` statement has no outputs declared.